# How to return to a specific state in angular

Tags: angularjs, state

In Angular, let's say I have a paginated list, and each item in the list has a link to a details page.  When a user clicks the details link for an item on page 2, a new page opens showing the details for that item.  When the user clicks 'back' or 'close', how can I go back to page 2 of the list?  Do I need to code something into the url of the close button, or is there a better way to do this by managing state?

Thanks

Comment: are you using `ngRoute`? The "defacto standard" replacement for `ngRoute` is ui-router, which is a state machine, and would seem to provide the features you are looking for.

Comment: Sharing a piece of code fiddle or http://jsfiddle.net/ would probably improve the question and encourage people to help.